# Disable Save As Pdf Option In Print Dialog

Tags: pdf, printing

I would like to disable or remove the Save as PDF option on the following print screen, is it possible in anyway? A solution with MDM capabilities or programmatically is acceptable.

[image: Print Screen Image]

What i tried so far is,

- Checked for a solution on the Android Application Programming side but as far as i see it is not possible.
- Checked the list of applications installed on the device to identify if this feature comes with a "print-service" application such as Cannon's or HP's print service applications. But did not see an app something like "Save as PDF print service", also this feature is not listed in settings->print-settings->print-services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get your hands on the source to rebuild the `/system/app/DocumentsUI/DocumentsUI.apk` and `/system/app/PrintSpooler/PrintSpooler.apk` since it relies on the first app, you can manage but any other way won't work for you